# find duplicates strings in arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

i need my program to go through the array list with all the clients telephone nr and print out the ones who have the same number. i register the numbers as strings and i tried this solution but i get an error...can somebody please help me?
thanks

```
boolean duplicates=false;
        for (int j=0;j<TelefonNrLista.size();j++)
          for (int k=j+1;k<TelefonNrLista.size();k++)
            if (k!=j && TelefonNrLista(k).getTelNr().equals(TelefonNrLista(j).getTelNr());
              duplicates=true;
    }
```

Comment: `StackTrace` please..

Comment: You have no closing parenthesis on your `if` statement. `k != j` is always `false` due to the inner loop construction.

Comment: @Phylogenesis do you mean its always true due to the inner loop?

Comment: ok this is my code now...it works if i only have 2 people with the same tel nr but it does not if i have more than 2....how do i get it right?

public static void listaTelNr() {    
         for(int y=0;y<TelefonNrLista.size();y++){
          for(int x=y+1;x<TelefonNrLista.size();x++){
         if (TelefonNrLista.get(x).getTelNr().equals(TelefonNrLista.get(y).getTelNr())){
        
          System.out.println(TelefonNrLista.get(y));
          System.out.println(TelefonNrLista.get(x));
         
                }
        }
         }
                }

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like this:

```
boolean duplicates=false;
for (int j=0;j<TelefonNrLista.size();j++) {
    for (int k=j+1;k<TelefonNrLista.size();k++) {
        if (k!=j && TelefonNrLista(k).getTelNr().equals(TelefonNrLista(j).getTelNr()) {
            duplicates=true;
        }
  }
}
```

The way you've done is not a good practice in Java.

Comment: You can reduce the first loop by 1 iteration as above, but that doesn't actually change the code.

Answer (score 0):

To find if it has duplicates you can use `HashSet` constructor for lists and check `size()` property...

```
Set noDuplicates = new HashSet(TelefonNrLista);

if (noDuplicates.size() < TelefonNrLista.size()){
    // do your stuff
}
```

Comment: You can't use a set like that, you don't know the details of the implementation of his custom class equals method. The getTelNr() method indicates he is using some custom class.

Comment: I totally agree with using HashSet, but in order to use it, u must first override hashCode and equals method

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a algorithm that looks something like this:

```
public Set<Client>lookForDuplicater(List<Client> TelefonNrLista  )
{
    Set<Client> duplicates = new Hashset<Client>(); // hash does not allow duplicates by definition
    Iterator<Client> iterator = TelefonNrLista.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()
    {
        Client current = iterator.next();
        Itarator2 = TelefonNrLista.iterator();
        while(iterator2.hasNext())
        {
            Client candidate = iterator2.next();
            // You don't want to compare the same instance
            if (current.equals(candidate) == false)
            {

              //  if (current.getTelNr()==candidate.getTelNr()) this for integer
                  if (current.getTelNr().equals(candidate.getTelNr())) // this works for strings
                {
                    duplicates.add(current);
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
    }
    return duplicates ;
}
```

With the returned Set you can easily check if it empty (duplicates.isEmpty()), if is empty it means it has no duplicates. If it not empty, the the duplicates are inside the set.

Comment: this won't be sufficient as equals and hashCode method have not been overridden